# Bootstrap Sticky with full width in container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to make a sticky that fill the full weith of the container in boostrap 4.
what i have made is this code bellow, the sticky work great but the full width in the container is not working, can some one help please, My HTML and CSS is like this:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <style>
      .content-section {
        background: lavender;
        height: 1000px;
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;
      }

      .sidebar-section {
        height: 100%;
      }

      .sidebar-content {
        background: cornflowerblue;
        padding: 1em;
      }
      </style>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Sticky Position Sidebar</title>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <style>
        </style>
      </head>
    <body>
      <article>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="title-section">
                <h1>Stacking Sticky Sidebars with Bootstrap 4</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
              <div class="content-section">
                Content Section
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
              <div class="sidebar-section">
                <div class="sidebar-item sticky-top">
                  <div class="sidebar-content">
                    Container 1
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap, the columns will span the full width, but columns have a 15px padding on the left and right sides, so your content inside the columns will not go to the edge of the column. You can add  `no-gutters` to the row to eliminate the padding on the columns.

The container div has 15px padding, which the rows cover with -15px margins, but since no-gutters removes the margin on the rows, the rows will be inside the padding on the container. You can get the rows to extend the full width of the screen by adding `px-0` to the container.

Also, you had your styles before the head section. Added styles should go inside the head and usually after any style sheets you’re loading.

And lastly, it’s best to setup your question using Stackoverflow’s snippet function so people can see the code in operation.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .content-section {
        background: lavender;
        height: 1000px;
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;
    }

    .sidebar-section {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-content {
        background: cornflowerblue;
        padding: 1em;
    }
</style>

<article>
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters bg-warning">
            <div class="col px-3">
                <div class="title-section">
                    <h1>Stacking Sticky Sidebars with Bootstrap 4</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-7 bg-success">
                <div class="content-section">
                    Content Section
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 bg-secondary">
                <div class="sidebar-section">
                    <div class="sidebar-item sticky-top">
                        <div class="sidebar-content">
                            Container 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi Rich, your answer is verry good. what do you think about my sulution bellow ? without changing html

Comment: Setting the left and right margins to -2rem gets your sidebar section to visually cover the screen, but now the sidebar is extending towards the right so you page has a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom. It’s better to use Bootstrap’s `no-gutters` class and overriding the margins. That way, everything fits within the screen width, so there’s no horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

It's realy easy without changin html css:

```
    .sidebar-section {
       margin: 0 -2rem 0 -2rem;
       width: auto;
     }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <style>
          .content-section {
            background: lavender;
            height: 1000px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            padding: 1em;
          }

          .sidebar-section {
            height: 100%;
          }

          .sidebar-content {
            background: cornflowerblue;
            padding: 1em;
          }
          
          .sidebar-section {
            margin: 0 -2rem 0 -2rem;
            width: auto;
           }
          </style>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Sticky Position Sidebar</title>
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384- 
     JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
            />
            <style>
            </style>
          </head>
        <body>
          <article>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="title-section">
                    <h1>Stacking Sticky Sidebars with Bootstrap 4</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                  <div class="content-section">
                    Content Section
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                  <div class="sidebar-section">
                    <div class="sidebar-item sticky-top">
                      <div class="sidebar-content">
                        Container 1
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </body>
        </html>
```